# dar formato carrusel bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

me he descargado un carrusel de imágenes de bootstrap ( https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-carousel )y estoy intentando según en qué dispositivo lo vea (pc, tablet o móvil) se vayan ocultando imágenes. Yo en el carrusel he dejado 3 imágenes y cuando paso a tablet debería dejar activas 2 imágenes y ocultar 1 y en móvil 1 imagen y ocultas 2 pero no sé como hacerlo.

En este carrusel al hacer responsive, las imágenes se me ponen en columna y no debería ser así, deberían seguir en línea o ocultarse.

Me podríais ayudar por favor o si sabéis de algún carrusel en el que se vaya ocultando el contenido según el responsive?

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Usa el siguiente código para el carrusel

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" id="Slide1" >
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" id="Slide2" >
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" id="Slide3" >
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Para ocultarlos en diferentes tamaños de pantalla debes hacer lo siguiente con css:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 780px)  {
   #Slide1
   {
       Display = none;
   }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)  {
   #Slide1
   {
       Display = none;
   }
   #Slide2
   {
       Display = none;
   }
}
```

Comment: He copiado el código que me pones y al probarlo sólo me aparece una imagen en todas las resoluciones, no sé que estoy haciendo mal cuando en teoría deberían aparecer las 3 imágenes cuando es tamaño de escritorio, 2 en tablet y 1 en móvil

Comment: Hola, si gustas pasarme tu código completo, tal vez podría identificar el problema viendo completo el css

Comment: Buenas, es el mismo código del enlace que puse por aquí [https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-carousel] lo único que cambié han sido las imágenes

Answer (score 0):

Mira el siguiente enlace:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

A mi me funcionó la documentación